# Retrieving AAD OpenID auth 'access_token' within a.NET Core 3.1 Web App

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to get OpenID connect auth to put the `access_token` into a cookie so I can use the access token to send an e-mail on behalf of the user using their Office365 account and `Microsoft.Graph` API.

Relevant lines from the **Startup.Configure** method:

```
   services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                 .AddCookie(options =>
                 {
                     options.LoginPath = "/Login";
                 })
                .AddAzureAD(options =>
                {
                    Configuration.Bind("AzureAD", options);
                });

    services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
                {
                    options.Authority += "/v2.0/";
                    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
    
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                });
```

Side Note

My OpenIdConnectOptions actually includes a few more things which I've omitted here, for example:

```
 options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
 options.Scope.Add("email");
 options.Scope.Add("Mail.Send");
```

After the user has logged into their Office365 account account, they're redirected back into the app, however, when I invoke         `var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");` null is returned.

I've spent hours getting nowhere with this, Any ideas?

Comment: you can look into the events in `options` in the line `AddAzureAD(options`

Comment: i don't think it is "access_token" in this case

Comment: Sorry, can you expand on that? thanks

Comment: look at the section using `OnCreatingTicket` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-5.0